# Mechanize ruby cannot see all content in linkedin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I've installed the mechanize gem in rails app and to test it I'm just copying and pasting the code below into the irb console. It logs into the page and I can put Orange into the search field and submit but then the next page has no content with "Orange" nor any of the orange employees that I see in my browser. Does linkedin have some security features to stop this or am I doing something wrong?

```
    require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

#create agent
agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| 
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari 4'
}
agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
#visit page
page = agent.get("https://www.linkedin.com/")

#login
login_form = page.form('login')
login_form.session_key = "email"
login_form.session_password = "password"
page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

# get the form
form = agent.page.form_with(:name => "commonSearch")
#fill form out
form.keywords = 'Orange France'
# get the button you want from the form
button = form.button_with(:value => "Search")
# submit the form using that button
agent.submit(form, button)

agent.page.link_with(:text => "Orange")
=> nil
```

Comment: Odds are really good they've got JavaScript loading content of their pages. Mechanize can't help you in that case. Instead of scraping though, you should look at [their API](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis).

Comment: @Mlennie did you get any work around?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Mechanize is it won't work directly with JavaScript loaded content, like the one found on this scenario using a LinkedIn search.

A solution for this is to look on the **page's body** and use regular expressions to get the desired content, and then parse the results as JSON.

For example:

```
url = "http://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?type=people&keywords=dario+barrionuevo"

results = agent.get(url).body.scan(/\{"person"\:\{.*?\}\}/)

person = results.first # You'd use an each here, but for the example we'll get the first

json = JSON.parse(person)
json['person']['firstName'] # => 'Dario'
json['person']['lastName'] # => 'Barrionuevo'
```